# New schema - Created Jar - Not showing in Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, xsd, pom.xml

I'm using STS editor.

1. created new JAXB project,

   imported schema (`abc.xsd`)

   Ran maven build, created jar with the version 1 in local repo.
2. In a project's (namely xyz-parent) `pom.xml` included dependency as

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>schema1</groupId>
     <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
     <version>1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. In a project's (namely xyz-integration whose parent is the project xyz-parent) `pom.xml` included dependency as

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>schema1</groupId>
     <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. In project xyz-integration I want to use classes from jar file. But I'm not seeing classes from jar file, not sure whether I'm missing anything here.

Please guide how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You schould probably install your artifact not just build it

`mvn install` will do.

The only exception from this if you are using multi module project - modules does not have to be explicitly installed.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i've been tried and still not available.

Answer (score 0):

I tried mvn clean package (you may try with mvn clean install or mvn clean verify whatever is relevant) and after that I restarted my STS IDE with the same workspace. Last but not least I also performed clean and build project.